# How to play a video strip backward in blender 2.8?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

If I select a specific strip from a clip in video sequencer and in strip tab under video -> playback direction -> backward, something funny happens. Can someone tell me whether there is some other way to play the video strip backward.I

Answer (score 1):

Check out your FPS readout in the **Preview** pane and the cache indicator in the **Sequence** view.

If your FPS is flashing red numbers that are lower rates than the source video, your machine's struggling to keep up.

[image]

Play in reverse `Shift-Ctrl-Spacebar` usually lags for me until the clip is mostly cached. You'll see the clip cache build as an orange bar below the tracks in Sequence.

[image]

Look into cache allocation via Blender's `Preferences ... System ... Sequencer Cache Limit` and into [Proxies](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/sequencer/properties/proxy_cache.html?highlight=proxies). These and other tips will help you squeeze more performance from your machine.